# My app publishing showing Application Error

Tags: reactjs, heroku

After developing my app using react, I successfully deployed to heroku,
but it refuses to open with the following message:

```
`An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail`
```

I headed to the log file and found something interesting but don't know how to  fix it.  here is the log below:
`

```
2020-10-14T14:15:14.528798+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://172.19.83.254/
2020-10-14T14:15:14.529231+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from 
2020-10-14T14:15:14.529319+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-10-14T14:15:14.529403+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: 404s will fallback to /
2020-10-14T14:15:14.529590+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-10-14T14:15:14.529591+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-14T14:15:14.610067+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-10-14T14:15:14.643427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-14T14:15:53.615814+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ai-eventapp.herokuapp.com request_id=5c18b5a5-e1ec-4abf-bdd4-9d4900ed60b3 fwd="105.112.97.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-14T14:16:01.737428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ai-eventapp.herokuapp.com request_id=89ca7f59-f5f6-45d4-9c57-816eca40f104 fwd="105.112.97.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-14T14:38:40.230120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-10-14T14:38:47.595040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-10-14T14:38:49.275783+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-14T14:38:49.275796+00:00 app[web.1]: > facialrecoq@0.1.0 start /app
2020-10-14T14:38:49.275796+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-10-14T14:38:49.275797+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-14T14:38:51.232697+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://172.17.12.222/
2020-10-14T14:38:51.233251+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from 
2020-10-14T14:38:51.233379+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-10-14T14:38:51.233492+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: 404s will fallback to /
2020-10-14T14:38:51.233731+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-10-14T14:38:51.233732+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-14T14:38:51.319442+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-10-14T14:38:51.353432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`
```

Comment: A status code of 0 is a clean exit, meaning no errors occurred, but the program **quit**, inspect your **server** code and make sure it starts to listen on some port

Comment: I have reviewed it again but can't find what the complaint is.  Meanwhile, the server is already hosted on Heroku and it's up and running.  Meanwhile, I can run the frontend from my local machine which is communicating with the server seamlessly.

Comment: see my server port listener ==> const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}...`));

Comment: https://github.com/Ajioz/faceDetectionApp   <-- Link to the server.  Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: see this:  2020-10-14T14:15:53.615814+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ai-eventapp.herokuapp.com request_id=5c18b5a5-e1ec-4abf-bdd4-9d4900ed60b3 fwd="105.112.97.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-14T14:16:01.737428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ai-eventapp.herokuapp.com request_id=89ca7f59-f5f6-45d4-9c57-816eca40f104 fwd="105.112.97.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https   It seems focus here, but  no clue to fixing it

Comment: Your repo has the whole node_modules folder committed to github....Add a gitignore file, and **do not commit node_modules**